# Remix 2.6.0, Vite (Unstable) -- Running into an import issue with React Bricks Library

Tags: reactjs, vite, remix.run

I see the issue, I have tried nearly everything to resolve the issue. Unless one of you smart Devs out there have a resolve I will be forced to compromise in one way or another. Thanks in advance.

`[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module virtual:remix/server-build: failed to import "/app/root.tsx"
|- /remix-brick-starter/node_modules/react-bricks/frontend/react-bricks-frontend.esm.js:1
import"intersection-observer";export{F as File,f as Image,L as Link,M as Meta,P as PageViewer,k as Preview,l as ReactBricks,h as Repeater,C as RichText,R as RichTextExt,T as Text,e as blockPluginConstructor,n as fetchPage,o as fetchPages,r as fetchTags,m as markPluginConstructor,p as plugins,s as renderJsonLd,t as renderMeta,a as useAdminContext,d as usePage,v as usePagePublic,i as usePageValues,b as usePages,c as usePagesPublic,u as useReactBricksContext,w as useTagsPublic,j as useVisualEdit}from"../react-bricks-8fe38110.esm.js";export{J as JsonLd,P as Plain,c as cleanPage,e as getPagePlainText,f as getSchemaOrgData}from"../react-bricks-510b2066.esm.js";export{t as types}from"../react-bricks-3e09ae2e.esm.js";import"react";import"classnames";import"react-lazy-load-image-component";import"axios";import"react-query";import"ts-md5";import"react-icons/fi";import"../react-bricks-4db2fafe.esm.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:356:17)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:305:7)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)`

Node Version 20.11.0

```
vite.config.ts --- 

import { unstable_vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { visualizer } from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";
import { cjsInterop } from "vite-plugin-cjs-interop";
import { remixDevTools } from "remix-development-tools/vite";

installGlobals();

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    remixDevTools(),
    remix({
      unstable_ssr: false,
      appDirectory: "app",
      ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
      publicPath: "/build/",
      serverModuleFormat: "esm",
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    cjsInterop({
      // List of CJS dependencies that require interop
      dependencies: ["react-bricks"],
    }),

    visualizer({ emitFile: true }),
  ],
});
```

```
tsconfig.json --- 

  "include": ["env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__generated__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["vitest/globals"],
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "NodeNext"
    },
    "esm": false,
    "files": true,
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

```
package.json ---

{
  "name": "remix-brick-starter",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix vite:build --profile",
    "codegen:brick": "tsx scripts/codegen-brick.ts",
    "codegen:brick-layout": "tsx scripts/codegen-brick-layout.ts",
    "codegen:component": "tsx scripts/codegen-component.ts",
    "dev": "node ./server.mjs",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint:css": "stylelint --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/stylelint \"app/**/*.css\"",
    "lint:js": "eslint --cache --ignore-path .gitignore --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "lint": "run-p lint:*",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "release": "ts-node scripts/release.ts",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server.mjs",
    "storybook:build": "storybook build",
    "storybook:chromatic": "chromatic --project-token=chpt_a644d03df3f91da --build-script-name=storybook:build",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006 --no-open",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
    "typecheck": "tsc -b"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource-variable/roboto-slab": "^5.0.18",
    "@fontsource/be-vietnam-pro": "^5.0.18",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.18",
    "@remix-run/css-bundle": "^2.6.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.6.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.6.0",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.6.0",
    "isbot": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bricks": "^4.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@csstools/postcss-global-data": "^2.1.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "^4.2.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typed-document-node": "^5.0.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.1.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers": "^4.0.4",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.6.0",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^2.6.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.11",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.7",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/test": "^7.6.13",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jsonp": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/negotiator": "^0.6.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^1.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "calver": "^22.9.1",
    "chromatic": "^10.9.3",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "husky": "^9.0.10",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "remix-development-tools": "^3.7.4",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.12.0",
    "storybook": "^7.6.13",
    "stylelint": "^16.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^14.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsx": "^4.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite-plugin-cjs-interop": "^2.0.5",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.1",
    "vitest": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint"
    ],
    "*.css": [
      "stylelint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can use a later version of Remix, however I like this setup. I know the workaround will be on the  React Bricks side.